# Karate framework fails to find tests in multi module Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, karate

Im trying to run my Karate tests with SpringBootTest but I'm getting the following error :

```
org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher handleThrowable
WARNING: TestEngine with ID 'junit-vintage' failed to discover tests
org.junit.platform.commons.util.PreconditionViolationException: Could not load class with name: com.user.EmployeeKarateTest
```

The Karate Test

```
import com.user.config.AbstractTestDefinition;
import com.intuit.karate.Results;
import com.intuit.karate.Runner;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

class EmployeeKarateTest extends AbstractTestDefinition {

    @Test
    void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:com/user/").tags("~@ignore").parallel(5);
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
    }
}
```

Hierarchy

```
.
├── common
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── resources
│               └── application.properties
├── karate
│   ├── karate.iml
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── src
│       ├── main
│       │   └── resources
│       │       └── karate-config.js
│       └── test
│           └── java
│               └── com
│                   └── user
│                       ├── config
│                       │   ├── AbstractTestDefinition.java
│                       │   └── KarateContextConfiguration.java
│                       ├── DeleteEmployeeTest.feature
│                       ├── EmployeeKarateTest.java
│                       ├── GetEmployeeTest.feature
│                       ├── PostEmployeeTest.feature
│                       └── PutEmployeeTest.feature
├── local-server
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── localServer
│                   ├── controllers
│                   │   ├── GreetingController.java
│                   │   └── PersonController.java
│                   ├── entities
│                   │   └── Person.java
│                   ├── services
│                   │   └── PersonService.java
│                   └── StartLocalServer.java
├── pom.xml
```

Master POM

```
<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java/com/user</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>com/user/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any help would really be appreciated.
Any help would really be appreciated.
Any help would really be appreciated.
Any help would really be appreciated.
Any help would really be appreciated.
Any help would really be appreciated.
Any help would really be appreciated.
Any help would really be appreciated.
Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was using jupiter with SpringBoot. The following dependencies resolved my issue.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

First I tried this and it worked:

```
mvn test -Dtest=EmployeeKarateTests
```

But yes `mvn test` doesn't work. But it does when you comment out the `<plugins>` piece in the `pom.xml`.

I leave it to you to figure out the magic combination of library dependencies (spring boot test, junit 5 / jupiter, and maven surefire) that will work :)